# Is it possible to proxify any function

Tags: c++

I use a (C) library with functions taking different parameters but always returning an int greater than zero in case of error:

```
int functionA(int param1, char param2); /* return an error code on failure, 0 otherwise */
int functionB(LIB_BOOLEAN param1);      /* return an error code on failure, 0 otherwise */
// ...
```

I would like to turn them all to be exception ready:

```
if (functionA(param1, param2) > 0)
{ throw std::runtime_error("Method failed"); }
```

Is it possible to write a template to do it once for all method ?

EDIT:
The idea is to avoid checking the result for each functions every time I use them.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What's wrong with `assert()`? Even better: unit tests.

Comment: You can certainly do it via a preprocessor macro.

Comment: What does *poxify* mean?

Comment: @tadman assert() doesn't throw

Comment: @Barmar I believe it’s a typo for “proxify”, that is, wrap in a proxy function that calls the C function, converting return codes into exceptions. OP seems to be asking whether it’s possible to do this for many functions in a convenient way.

Comment: If you've got functions that return values you need to check those values, it's the responsibility of the caller. If the function is being fed data it can't deal with, throw an exception if that's an appropriate course of action. Defensive programming leads to a false sense of security and hides bugs.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, it was a typo, I wanted to mean "proxify"

Comment: If the return value is important, I would suggest making a custom exception class that stores it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto my_invoke(F &&f, Args&&... args) {
    if(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Method failed");
    }
}
```

You can call it as;

```
my_invoke(functionA, 0, 'c');
```

Comment: It's been quite some time since I don't do C++, but what does && means here?

Comment: @strep  <insane laughter>

Comment: @streppel In this case it's a _forwarding reference_. [Here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) is a good explanation (using the _old_ name, _universal reference_).

Comment: @NeilButterworth LOL this fits the situation quite nicely

Comment: Or to _very_ heavily paraphrase the link for anyone with bandwidth concerns... For any deduced type `T`, forwarding reference `T&&` is "reference `T&` if passed an lvalue, or rvalue reference `T&&` if passed an rvalue."  (Where an rvalue reference is a reference to a temporary object.)  For example, given `std::string s = "Lvalue";` and `template<typename T> void func(T&& t);`, `func(s)` will be `func(std::string&)`, and `func("Rvalue")` will be `func(std::string&&)`.

Comment: @streppel Just you wait. THREE &s can't be far off

Comment: I was looking for something like that, thanks! For info: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dKVBRjtIrJjoAMfE

Answer (score 2):

Here is a template-based solution using C++17's new `auto` template parameters:

```
template <auto &> struct CallerImpl;

template <typename ...Args, int (&F)(Args ...)>
struct CallerImpl<F>
{
    static int CallOrThrow(Args ... args)
    {
        if (int n = F(args...); n > 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("Method failed");
        else
            return n;
    }
};

template <auto & F, typename ... Brgs>
int CallOrThrow(Brgs ... brgs)
{
    return CallerImpl<F>::CallOrThrow(brgs...);
}
```

Usage example:

```
int foo(double, char)
{
    std::cout << "Foo called\n";
    return 8;
}

CallOrThrow<foo>(1.5, 'x');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use c++17 but it looks like promising :)

Comment: @FloFu: Right, if you don't mind having the client function be a function parameter and not a template parameter, then the other solution is definitely the way to go. But this kind of "typed delegate" hadn't been possible before (at least not quite so directly), so I thought I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'll get downvoted for this, but I honestly think this is one case where the preprocessor can usefully be used:

```
#define CHECK( fn ) \
    { \
        if( fn > 0 ) { \
            throw "problem"; \
        } \
    } 


int f(int x) {
    return x - 1;
}


int main() {
    CHECK( f(42) );
}
```

It's clear, it's short, it's simple, and it could be made to make use of the `__LINE__`, `__FILE__` and other pre-defined macros, which you can't do with templates.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename ... A> void executeFunction(int(*func_ptr)(A...), A...) {
   if (func_ptr(A...) > 0)
     throw std::runtime_error("Method failed"); 
}

int func(int A, int B) {
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    a = 0;
    b = 4;
    executeFunction(func, a, b)
}
```

Not tested but something like this should work.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one approach that doesn’t require changing call sites. Assuming these C functions all have the same convention for return codes, you can write a wrapper that converts the return code to an exception.

```
inline void checked(const char *name, int result) {
    if (result > 0)
        throw std::runtime_error(name);
}
```

Then introduce a preprocessor definition for each function.

```
#define functionA(...) checked("functionA", functionA(__VA_ARGS__))
```

This works because `functionA` will not be expanded within the definition of the `functionA` macro. And variadic macros are standard since C++11.

Comment: Alternatively, [you could use a single wrapper](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d01560401d1b55f), `#define Wrapper(Func, ...) checked(#Func, Func(__VA_ARGS__))`.

Comment: @JustinTime: True. There’s a tradeoff: this way, if you forget to add a `#define` for a function then it won’t be checked; that way, the same thing happens if you forget to wrap at a call site. However, I figure there are probably more call sites than functions, and that it’s easier to forget to wrap every call, so it makes sense to wrap the whole library once.